# How can I updating setstate for object in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two objects:
first state

```
[{ "orders": [{ "id": "1587881", "uid": "237603" }, { "id": "1587880", "uid": "237603" }] }]
```

and add new data

```
[{ "orders": [{ "id": "1587879", "uid": "237603" }, { "id": "1587878", "uid": "237603" }] }]
```

i need get new state

```
[{ "orders": [{ "id": "1587881", "uid": "237603" }, { "id": "1587880", "uid": "237603" }, { "id": "1587879", "uid": "237603" }, { "id": "1587878", "uid": "237603" }] }]
```

Pleas help me!

I try it

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Orders extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [{ "orders": [{ "id": "1587881", "uid": "237603" }, { "id": "1587880", "uid": "237603" }] }]
    };
  }

  loadingData = () => {
    const add = [{ "orders": [{ "id": "1587879", "uid": "237603" }, { "id": "1587878", "uid": "237603" }] }];
    this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, ...add] });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadingData();
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.state.data);


    return (
      <div className="page" >
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Orders;
```

But I am not getting a single array of data ... two separate arrays are created. How can I fix this?

P.S. I am receiving data in this format and I cannot fix the format of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying that the state `data` is an array of objects, this response is assuming that you will add orders to the same first index on that array.

```
loadingData = () => {
    const add = [{ "orders": [{ "id": "1587879", "uid": "237603" }, { "id": "1587878", "uid": "237603" }] }];
    this.setState(oldState => {
      const newData = { ...oldState.data };
      add[0].orders.forEach(x => newData[0].orders.push(x));
      return { data: newData };
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, but i get two arrays...

Comment: two arrays? what do you mean?

Comment: orders: Array(3)0: {id: "1587881", uid: "237603"}1: {id: "1587880", uid: "237603"}3: (2) [{…}, {…}]

Comment: but i need  Array(4)0: {id: "1587881", uid: "237603"}1: {id: "1587880", uid: "237603"}3: {id: "1587879", uid: "237603"}4: {id: "1587878", uid: "237603"}

Comment: I see, updating the response

Comment: OK. I wait. I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: Try the solution I just uploaded. This might not be the pretiest solution, but it works on my local.

Comment: Not working.... log - 
orders.js:29 [{…}]0: {orders: Array(3)}length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
orders.js:29 {0: {…}}0: orders: Array(3)0: {id: "1587881", uid: "237603"}1: {id: "1587880", uid: "237603"}2: {orders: Array(2)}length: 3[[Prototype]]: Array(0)[[Prototype]]: Object[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: retry again please

Comment: By the way, why not to use functional components?

Comment: Thank you. Now working.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-lederberg-i3rtb?file=/src/App.js

You can do destructering on the first element of the array and then rebuild the way you want.

```
  const array1 = [
{
  orders: [
    { id: "1587881", uid: "237603" },
    { id: "1587880", uid: "237603" }
  ]
}
];
const array2 = [
{
  orders: [
    { id: "1587879", uid: "237603" },
    { id: "1587878", uid: "237603" }
  ]
}
];

const [firstEl] = array1;
const [secondEl] = array2;
// Update your state here
setOrders([{ orders: { ...firstEl.orders, ...secondEl.orders } 
}])
console.log([{ orders: { ...firstEl.orders, ...secondEl.orders } 
}]);
```

Comment: I do think my answer should be the accepted one. Vlad please let me know if this was of any help :)